# Cordova iOS window.location not working

Tags: cordova

I have a hello world Cordova app created and I'm trying to load my existing SPA web app. Here's my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Winetracker.co</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script>
          function onDeviceReady() {
            if (navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
              navigator.notification.alert('An internet connection is required to continue');
            } else {
              window.location="https://app.winetracker.co";
            }
          }
          document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's my config.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="co.winetracker.app" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Winetracker.co</name>
    <description>
        The easiest way to keep track of the wine you drink.
    </description>
    <author email="tony@winetracker.co" href="http://winetracker.co">
        Winetracker.co
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <allow-navigation href="*://*.winetracker.co/*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

I've gone through several tutorials and tried several variations (like just linking to google.com instead or a test.html file) but I'm sure I'm just missing something. Any fresh eyes see the problem?

Comment: Same issue when I build to Android emulator too.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out there was a blocking issue with a javascript security policy.

I swapped out the  line with the following, and it worked perfectly:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com *; style-src *  'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'  'unsafe-eval' *; connect-src *; media-src *">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">

    <title>Winetracker.co</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

    <script>
      function onDeviceReady() {
      alert("Nonnnn");
        if (navigator.connection.type == 'Unknown connection') {
          navigator.notification.alert('An internet connection is required to continue');
        } else {
          window.location="https://app.winetracker.co";
        }
      }
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    </script>
</body>
```